# FlickityCall - prev/next event programmatically

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, flickity

To properly handle my carousel I use [flickity](https://flickity.metafizzy.co/extras.html).

It works fine, but I'm currently trying to navigate with custom buttons.

Docs say to call `carousel.flickity("next")` - which I tried, but I doesn't seem to work.

```
import * as Flickity from 'flickity';

this.$elem = value.nativeElement;
this.carousel = new Flickity(this.$elem, {
  accessibility: true,
  prevNextButtons: false,
  pageDots: false,
  setGallerySize: false,
  draggable: true,
  freeScroll: true
});
```

**Is there an equivalent to call the next event programmatically using javascript/typescript?**

Comment: Try ```prevNextButtons: true``` in your Flickity constructor

Comment: @AbhinabRajopadhyaya I want to use custom buttons, independent from the flickity slider itself, but executing the next event.

Answer (score 1):

Hey I got a solution for that. Use query selector to access Flickity given next buttons and click them programmatically on your custom button onClick functions. You can hide the buttons given by Flickity using css. This is a work around but not based on official docs.

```
/* 
    In my case I inspected the button given by Flickity and accessed those in my JS or TS file 
*/

 let temp:any = document.querySelector('.flickity-button.flickity-prev-next-button.next');
 temp.click();
```

In your CSS file you can add visibility property hidden so that button functionality will be intact to click programmatically but in UI as expected Flikity buttons wont be found.

```css
.flickity-button {
    position: absolute;
    visibility: hidden;
    border: none;
    color: #8c6238 !important;
}
```